# How to enter a YYYYMM date in Jekyll?

Tags: date, jekyll, github-pages

How should dates be entered in Jekyll?

I would like to enter the date "August 2018" in a YAML file to be used in Jekyll. I find lots of information on how to format already-existing dates, but pretty much nothing on how to **enter** them.

The best I have managed to find is [Date formatting](https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/date-formatting/), which implies that dates entered in ISO 8601 format should be valid. If I run with this, then [Wikipedia explicitly states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#General_principles)

> "2004-05" is a valid ISO 8601 date, which indicates May (the fifth
>   month) 2004.

This implies that "August 2018" could be entered as `2018-08`.

However, when I use my YAML file my_data.yml in my _data folder

```
date: 2018-08
```

then Jekyll doesn't recognize it as a date as

```
{{ site.data.my_data.date | time: '%B %Y' }}
```

outputs "2018-08" and not "August 2018".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: Enter YYYYMM dates such as "August 2018" as `Aug 2018`.**

Searching through the [Jekyll repo](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/), I found the [date filters](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/035ea729ff5668dfc96e7f56a86d214e5a633291/lib/jekyll/filters/date_filters.rb). The Ruby on Rails method `.to_formatted_s` ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/to_formatted_s)) seem to be key to most of them. In the source to that method dates are written as `Tue, 04 Dec 2007 00:00:00 +0000` from which I guessed that I should write `Aug 2018`. Doing so in my_data.yml, the code outputs the expected “August 2018”.